# How to get distinct count of occurrence of string

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following string

```
A7sus4, A, A#, A#4, A#7, A#dim, B11, Bm6, Gmaj7
```

I would like to get the first value of each block of data like so

```
A, A, A, A, A, A, B, B, G
```

and then further break this down so that at the end I get a count of each distinct occurrence to get

```
A,6
B,2
G,1
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What is `data` in your code? What *exactly* do you expect to get out?

Comment: Please explain little bit more, People here are Programmer and not Music enthusiast. So, care to explain what is "root note" , what you tried so far and what exactly is desired result to be extracted in laymen's language ?

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to even know how to ask a question but I will try to do better next time! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table for counting, where the root cord note is the key.

```js
var data = [{ cordname: 'A7sus4', fingering: '002030', fret: 1 }, { cordname: 'A', fingering: 'x02220', fret: 1 }, { cordname: 'A#', fingering: 'x13331', fret: 1 }, { cordname: 'A#4', fingering: 'xx3341', fret: 1 }, { cordname: 'A#7', fingering: 'xx1112', fret: 3 }, { cordname: 'A#dim', fingering: 'xx2323', fret: 1 }, { cordname: 'B', fingering: '', fret: -1 }],
    count = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(a => count[a.cordname[0]] = (count[a.cordname[0]] || 0) + 1);
console.log(count);
```

Second attempt, for edited question with splitting the astring and younting the first character of the strings.

```js
var data = 'A7sus4, A, A#, A#4, A#7, A#dim, B11, Bm6, Gmaj7'.split(', '),
    count = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(a => count[a[0]] = (count[a[0]] || 0) + 1);
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
var d = ["A","B","A","A","A","C","A","C"];
```

Then

```
['A','B','C'].forEach(x => console.log(x, d.filter(f => (f==x)).length));
```

Assuming the 1st array lists the notes to look for.

To grab a result object

```
var r = {};
['A','B','C','D'].forEach(x => r[x] = d.filter(f => (f==x)).length);
```